# What exactly is expo.constants?

Tags: react-native, expo

I keep seeing around can someone provide an easy to understand break down.

why is it in the styles sheet?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the documentaion of [Expo constants here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants)

Basically, the constants are an object with multiple values depending on the phone, installation, os, etc... You should refer to the linked doc to know more about wich information you can find.

For the stylesheet:

```
paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
```

means: you will set a `paddingTop` to your component equal to the status bar, and since the status bar height changes with each (android / ios) device, you can't just put a fixed value.

Comment: ok do i have to put the constant stuff only in my App.js file or every .js file i create ?

Comment: You only need To put it when you need a value from it.